# Troubleshooting Custom Styling Issues with PRIME NG's <p-button> Component in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng, web-frontend

When working with PRIME NG in my Angular application, I've encountered a situation where a custom style is not being applied to my `<p-button>`. Here are the scenarios I've tested and their results:

1. **Works: Red Button**

   ```js
   @Component({
     selector: 'my-button',
     template: ` <p pButton class="custom_button" label="Click"></p> `,
     styles: [
       `
         .custom_button {
           background: red;
         }
       `,
     ],
   })
   ```

   In this case, the custom style with a red background is correctly applied to the button.
2. **Works: Yellow Button**

   ```js
   @Component({
     selector: 'my-button',
     template: ` <p pButton class="custom_button" label="Click"></p> `,
     styles: [
       `
         .p-button {
           background: yellow;
         }
       `,
     ],
   })
   ```

   This scenario also works as expected, resulting in a yellow button.
3. **Doesn't Work: Blue Button**

   ```js
   @Component({
     selector: 'my-button',
     template: ` <p-button class="custom_button" label="Click"></p-button> `,
     styles: [
       `
         .p-button {
           background: yellow;
         }
       `,
     ],
   })
   ```

   Unfortunately, in this case, the custom style with a yellow background is not being applied to the `<p-button>`. It seems like there might be an issue specific to styling `<p-button>` elements.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: You are not using PrimeFaces.

Comment: use styleClass on prime components, you might need to use ::ng-deep depending if the class is component specific